# I don't fully understand this implementation despite seeing documentation (subtle crypto)

Tags: javascript, api, browser, cryptography, cryptoapi

What do each individual letters(e and n respectively) represent and what is the code afterward (RSAPSS forward)? I have a general idea - but I would appreciate a more thorough break down of the problem. Thank you for your time.

```
window.crypto.subtle.importKey("jwk", {
      kty: "RSA",
      e: "AQAB",
      n: "vGO3eU16ag9zRkJ4AK8ZUZrjbtp5xWK0LyFMNT8933evJoHeczexMUzSiXaLrEFSyQZortk81zJH3y41MBO_UFDO_X0crAquNrkjZDrf9Scc5-MdxlWU2Jl7Gc4Z18AC9aNibWVmXhgvHYkEoFdLCFG-2Sq-qIyW4KFkjan05IE",
      alg: "PS256",
      ext: true,
                  },
      RSAPSS, false, ["verify"])
      .then(ok("rsa-pss", "importKey", "jwk-pub"))
      .catch(err("rsa-pss", "importKey", "jwk-pub"));
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation to see what those parameters represent?

Comment: `n` looks like the key, probably base-64 encoded.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#dfn-SubtleCrypto-method-importKey

Comment: The second argument is a [JSON Web Key](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7517)